# Relational algebra, finding how many a number is called

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I have a table as below

```
callingNumber | calledNumber 
-----------------------------
n1            | n2
n2            | n6
n9            | n3
n1            | n2
n2            | n1
```

I want to know how to get a result like this

```
callingNumber | calledTimes
----------------------------
n1            | 1
n2            | 2
n9            | 0
```

So the result will display only the calling numbers ( who initiate the call) and how many times theys have been called ( they occur in the "calledNumber" field ),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start with a list of all numbers you want and then join in the ones being summarized:

```
select cn.callingNumber, count(t.calledNumber) as cnt
from (select distinct callingNumber from table t) cn left outer join
     table t
     on cn.callingNumber = t.calledNumber
group by cn.callingNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select calledNumber,COALESCE(calledTimes,0)
FROM (
      SELECT calledNumber,Count(*) as calledTimes
      FROM TableName
      GROUP BY calledNumber
     )Z
RIGHT JOIN TableName t
   ON t.callingNumber=z.calledNumber
```

Comment: Thank you, but this will not display the last line in the result:
n9 | 0